# Android: Nested tabactivities doesn't work with startActivityForResult

Tags: android, tabs, nested

When I nest a TabActivity inside another TabActivity, startActivityForResult fails when called from the inner tabactivity. The new activity starts, but I get an error message:

```
startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent
```

and onActivityResult is never called when the activity returns.

Code to reproduce found below. Four classes, MyActivity is the main class with two tabs, NestedTab has three tabs, all tabs containt SimpleActivity with a button that calls SimpleDialog:

```
public class MyActivity extends TabActivity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Populate a couple of tabs
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SimpleActivity.class);
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Repeat
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, NestedTab.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("nested").setIndicator("Nested tabs")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

 }
}

public class NestedTab extends TabActivity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent(this, SimpleActivity.class);

    String tabs[]= {"One", "Two", "Three"};
    for (String s : tabs)
    {
        intent.putExtra("name", s);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(s).setIndicator(s).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }


}

public class SimpleActivity extends Activity {
Button mBtn;
Context mCtx;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple);
    mCtx = this;
    mBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
     mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
             startActivityForResult(new Intent(mCtx, SimpleDisplay.class), 1);
         }
     });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    Toast.makeText(this, "Activity finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}


public class SimpleDisplay extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText("Just hit back button");
    setContentView(text);

}
}
```

Not able to paste the xml files but main is identical to step 4: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

and simple is just a textview and a button.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have to rethink your application design if you nest a `TabActivity` inside another `TabActivity`.

Comment: We feel this is the natural way to present our dataset and is a very common way to do it. E.g. appstore on iphone has Top 25 with submenu options Top paid, top free and top grossing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `SimpleActivity.this.startActivity` or `((Activity) view.getContext()).startActivity` instead of just `startActivity`. You're firing off the Activity from your `OnClickListener` instead of from your `Activity` otherwise, hence the error and the lack of callback to the Activity's `onActivityResult`.

EDIT: Ah, I missed the double-nested bit. Things get all kind of weird when you double-nest TabActivity with intents at both levels -- look at the source code for `TabActivity` to see what goes on there, and you should be able to emulate its behavior if you really want to.

The long and short of it is that your onActivityResult will only get propagated down one level; if you really really want to create an Intent-based sub-subtab (as opposed to Intent-based tabs with normal view-based subtabs) you'll need to have the parent (single-nested) tab fire off the Intent. To do that, try setting your single-nested tab to have a method like called something like `startActivityAndDispatchToChild`, and call that from the child with `getParent().startActivityAndDispatchToChild`. Have that method startActivityForResult, and override the `getActivityResult` method on the single-nested tab use the code coming back from the child to figure out which child to dispatch to. Using that code, call `getLocalActivity().getActivity(whateverTag)` to dispatch to the proper subactivity.

But don't do that. Just have your second-level activity use View-based rather than Intent-based content; if you really want to separate out what the sub-sub-pages do somewhat, write a custom ViewGroup class to manage the content for each subtab.

Comment: None of these two helps unfortunately. Note also that if the Nestedtab is made the main class (changing the mainfest) so that it's the only tabactivity, everything works just fine... Could it be that the context is messed up because the tabactivity is created inside the onCreate of the first tabactivity somehow?

Comment: Right, I had a feeling something like this would be the answer. Thanks!

Comment: a rather contrived explanation but still filled the gap. being in a similar situation, my code: 
Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), StatusHelperActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

was not working because second line should have been 

getParent().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

That being added, there really is no need for giving up on Activities in favour of awkward Viewgroup extensions that do not have any trail of life (cycle ^^). +1